# How to erase a player with a given name from a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, erase-remove-idiom

I'm seeing some big bad error messages whilst trying to erase a string from a vector. I'm trying to use the erase-remove idiom but it's not working. Here are some snippets to show my predicament.

```
team.players.erase( remove(team.players.begin(), team.players.end(),
                            player_name), team.players.end());
```

team.players is declared in this struct:

```
struct team 
{
    string name;
    player captain;
    vector<player> players;

};
```

The vector team.players is populated dynamically as the program runs, and at some point a user has the option to remove a player via a menu.

```
if (select_option == PRINT_TEAM) print_team(team);
    if (select_option == CHANGE_TEAM_NAME) change_team_name(team);
    if (select_option == CHANGE_CAPTAIN) change_captain(team);
    if (select_option == ADD_PLAYER) add_player(team);
    if (select_option == REMOVE_PLAYER) remove_player(team);
    if (select_option == QUIT) exit(0);
```

However I'm getting these errors as I tried to compile my program (clang++), long before the function is called. Here are the errors:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:865:22: error:      invalid operands to binary expression ('player' and 'const      std::__1::basic_string<char>')
        if (*__first == __value_)
            ~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:2125:22: note:
      in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::find<std::__1::__wrap_iter<player *>, std::__1::basic_string<char> >'
      requested here
    __first = _VSTD::find(__first, __last, __value_);
                     ^
program2.cpp:172:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::remove<std::__1::__wrap_iter<player *>, std::__1::basic_string<char>
      >' requested here
    team.players.erase( remove(team.players.begin(), team.players.end(),
                        ^
2 errors generated.
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: please show a [mcve].

Comment: How about creating an `operator==` function which compares a `player` object to a `std::string`? Because that's the problem the compiler is telling you about, that you try to compare a `player` object with a `std::string`.

Comment: your vector contains `player`s so you cant erase a string from it :P

Comment: Did you forget to write an equality operator to compare `team` against the type of `player_name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is quite cryptic, especially for beginners, but it seems that the compiler is unable to find out an `operator==` implementation to compare instances of your `player` class with `std::string` objects.

Maybe what you really want is using `std::remove_if`, specifying a custom condition in which you compare the player's name with the `std::string` storing the name to remove.

You can express this custom condition using a lambda, e.g. :

```
team.players.erase( 
    std::remove_if(
        team.players.begin(), 
        team.players.end(),

        [&player_name](const player& p) {
            return p.name == player_name;
        }),
    team.players.end()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), not `std::remove`. You will have to provide a function that takes a player (const reference to avoid copying) and returns bool.

e.g. (Assumes `player` has a string member `name`)

```
team.players.erase( 
    remove_if(
        team.players.begin(), 
        team.players.end(), 
        [&player_name](const player & p) { return p.name == player_name }), 
    team.players.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `std::remove()` function uses `bool operator==()` to compare elements of the `std::vector<player>` with the `player_name` variable, which is of type `std::string`.

That's the way how `std::remove()` recognizes, which elements of the vector it should erase (or, better, move at the end of the container).

However, there is no `bool operator==(const player& p, const std::string& name)` defined, which is not surprising, as you would have to do it by yourself. Better approach, in this case, IMHO is to use `std::remove_if()` instead of `std::remove()`, because `std::remove_if()` takes a **unary function** (a function taking one argument and returning bool), which it calls in order to find out if it should remove the element or not.

```
team.players.erase(remove_if(team.players.begin(), team.players.end(),
    [&player_name](const auto& player) { return player.name == player_name; });
```

(NOTE: I assumed that `player` class/struct has a member `name` of type `std::string`).

If you would like to try the `operator==()` approach, you would have to define
something like this:

```
bool operator==(const player& p, const std::string& name) {
    return p.name == name;
}

bool operator==(const std::string& name, const player& p) {
    return p.name == name;
    // Or, to be more general, you could use
    // return operator==(p, name);
    // here (to call the operator==() version with switched arguments)
}
```

(Yes, you should return both versions, as - in general - comparison using `==` should be symmetric).